# How to configure filebeat for logstash cluster environment?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, cluster-computing, filebeat, elk

I am missing something very basic when I think of how Filebeat will be configured in a clustered logstash setup.

As per the article 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/deploying-and-scaling.html
and this architecture diagram
[image: scalable logstash deployment]
I think that there is some kind of load balancer in front of the logstash cluster. However, the Filebeat output documentation suggests that there must be an array of all the Logstatsh nodes specified. Using this list of nodes, Filebeat will do the load balancing from the client-side.

Also as per [this](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2632) GitHub issue, there is no native logstash clustering available yet.

So, my question is, what kind of setup do I need to be able to point my multiple Filebeat to one logstash service endpoint without specifying the logstash nodes in the cluster?

- Is it possible?
- Would having load balancer in front of Logstash cluster be of any help?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Logstash clustering feature is still in the works and you don't want to specify all the Logstash hosts inside all your Beats configurations, then the only solution I see is to use a TCP load balancer in front of Logstash.

All your Beats would point to that load balancer endpoint and you can manage your Logstash cluster behind that load balancer as you see fit. Be aware, though, that you're adding a hop (hence latency) between your Beats and your Logstash cluster.